# monorepo with webpack (how to include assets in build)

Tags: webpack, monorepo

I'm trying to create monorepo which will contain components that are built with typescript and sass. Folder structure looks like this:

```
- packages
    - components
        - src
            - Slider
                - Slider.ts
                - Slider.scss
            - Modal
                - Modal.ts
                - Modal.scss
        - webpack.config.js
    - app1
        - src
            - index.ts (imports `components`)
        - webpack.config.js
    - app2
        - src
            - index.ts (imports `components`)
        - webpack.config.js
```

I want to use components in app1 and app2. What I tried is building components with `DllPlugin` and referencing it in app1 and app2 with `DllReferencePlugin`, it works well for typescript files, but what about scss, images, fonts and other assets? When building app1 or app2, I want their dist folder to include all assets from components. The reason why I'm not importing directly `components/src/Modal` without dll plugin is that components folder may have different webpack configuration like alias for example. What's the best practice for accomplishing this?